# What's the best way to care for and feed my strawberry plants?

Tags: growth, fruits, organic, strawberries

Now that strawberry season is upon us, I wanted to be proactive to maximize the output of my 7-8 small strawberry plants.  I have had these plants for 4 years now and the results have been mixed in terms of fruit production.  I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong. Any guidance as to what I should or shouldn't with these plants to get good results this season would be appreciated.  I am into organic gardening so organic suggestions only please.

Comment: What variety (or varieties) of strawberries do you have?

Comment: I think they are the june everbearing one's (small in size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strawberry plants can produce fruit for 6 years or so but production rapidly drops off after the first few years with onset of diseases and pests.  So, the best thing to do is toss them and start again.

Next time you could propagate new plants from runners so that you keep renewing your stock.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/basics/techniques/growfruitandveg_strawberries1.shtml